# How to return simple html response with MessagingExtensionActionResponse for a Teams Bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

```
    protected override Task<MessagingExtensionActionResponse> OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitActionAsync(
        ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, MessagingExtensionAction action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {


        return Task.FromResult(new MessagingExtensionActionResponse
        {

            ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult
            {

                 Type = "message",                     
                 Text ="<div><pre>Hello</pre></div>" 
            }
        });

    }
```

I dont want a hero card that takes up space, just simple plain HTML response like the example above, but i dont know how to do it. The above example dont work.

Answer (score 2):

Currently OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitActionAsync method does not support html response .It has the following options for responding.

> - No response - You can choose to use the submit action to trigger a
>     process in an external system, and not provide any feedback to the
>     user. This can be useful for long-running processes, and you may
>     choose to provide feedback in another manner (for example, with a
>     proactive message.
> - Another task module - You can respond with an
>     additional task module as part of a multi-step interaction.
> - Card response - You can respond with a card that the user can then interact
>     with and/or insert into a message.
> - Adaptive Card from bot - Insert an Adaptive Card directly into the conversation.
> - Request the user authenticate
> - Request the user provide additional configuration

[Doc Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/respond-to-task-module-submit?tabs=dotnet)

Comment: I am looking to output a simpler card then hero card or adaptive card. Best case if i could remove my extension icon and name in the card output that would work for me.

Comment: do you have an example of removing it=?

Comment: You could create a simple adaptive card and add text field only. But you cannot remove the extension icon and name from it. It is added by bot botframework in Teams

Comment: Thats what i did, but for my application the icon and name takes up much space given that i only want to show a small quote of conversation.  Are there any chance that its on the roadmap to return pure HTML ?

Comment: Currently this is not planned out. Can you pelase make a features suggestions on [Microsoft Teams feedback portal on UserVoice](https://aka.ms/microsoftteamsplatformsuggestions)

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet response: MS Bot does not support HTML, use MarkDown instead => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/reference-markdown-format. However, not all the HTML element are available, below an example with hyperlink.

```
turnContext.SendActivity("[LINK TITLE](URL)");
```